# Adding Localytics to a Unity3D Facebook Web app

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine

I am trying to implement Localytics tagging into a Facebook web app. We have already put Localytics into the mobile app using Prime31 plugins. I took Unity3D's generated HTML file and added javascript code which makes calls to a localytics.js file (the localytics framework), it appears that the calls are getting made when things are tested in the browser. However, when the app is uploaded onto the facebook app page, it seems as if the calls localytics calls are not getting made. Any help or insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I lead the SDK team here at Localytics. All of our SDKs have optional logging, which should help you diagnose whether or not the SDK is being called. You can find details on how to enable logging here:

http://www.localytics.com/docs/sdks-integration-guides/web/#html5options

If you're not able to diagnose the issue with logging, please send us mail at support@localytics.com and we can assist you further.